# Convert a plain picture into shape in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to create a chloropeth map consisting of 77 districts within a country in Excel. For that I pulled out individual districts by using photoshop but that's in picture format. The problem with picture format is I can't dock them together to assemble the whole map, but a shape can be perfectly docked together.
Is there a way to convert those picture format into shapes format?

Comment: Try this online convert web: https://vectormagic.com/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to convert the pictures of the districts to a shape (which will be kind of difficult), you could try using a map chart.

Say I have a simple list of data showing the relative awesomeness of three states:

[image]

I can select that data and use Insert>Charts>Maps>Filled Map to create a map based on my data.

[image]

Note that when you first create the map, you may see a yellow bar at the top of the Chart saying "Your data will be sent to bing" (or words to that effect). Click OK on that message if you see it. It simply sends the list of geographies to an online service to retrieve the shape of each geography.

[image]

In addition to this, if you want to add statistical facts or additional metadata to your list of geographies, you can select the list and use the Data>Data Types>Geography button. After doing that, you will see a small icon next to each geography. You can then use the field picker to add data from the web.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Does excel have the districts of Nepal? 

Comment: I'm trying to do it into map of Nepal, but that's not available.

Comment: No, there is not